# How to access HttpResponse sent from server (javax.servelt used) on client

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

I am new to everything client server related and I just started to learn writing servlets in java. The question I am asking surely has been asked before but I just don't quite know where/what to look for.

What I have: A servlet in java and a jsp page. Those two can communicate over tomcat. My servlet receives a POST request and using the HttpRequest object it calculates something on the server side and creates an array of json objects. 
I know that i have to save the result in my HttpResponse and I sent the response via response dispatcher.

Now I want to access that array of json objects. I know I will have to parse all json objects on my client side in order to do something with it on my client side. What I don't know is:

where do I save the response on my client side? As a global variable? Do I save it somewhere on the clients local memory? Do I use Javascript? I don't need code examples but if someone can direct me to the right directions meaning:
what are the right expressions/words to use to search for the right answers? Do I need some libraries? I am thankful for any help/advice.

Comment: Unless you're doing Ajax, the response just changes the page in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set attribute to request `request.setAttribute("name","value");`
2. call the dispatcher to forward to jsp,
3. access this attribute in jsp: `${name}`